# PHP program that gets an array with elements

Tags: php, arrays

I try to take elements from an array in php I have to check if the element is a string integer or a floating point number. Also, I have to display the result in a paragraph in the tree group the input is:

```
Bow
18
Alaska
4.5
France
1.5
10
13
45.1
```

The output is:
Group 1 - integers:
must be an integer

Group 2 - floats:
must be a float

Group 3 - strings
must be a string

My code is as follows it is totally wrong:

```
<?php
$elements = [];
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
  $elements[] = trim($line);
}
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $data=(int)$element;
    if($data>0){
        print "<p>"."integers: ".$data." ,"."</p>";
    }elseif($data===0){
        print "<p>"."strings: ".$element."</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: [`gettype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype)

Answer (score 0):

Because your input is text (and your are trimming each value), every `$element` will be a string.  You will not be able to use standard `is_int()` or `is_float()` functions on these strings.

It may be fastest to cast the strings as a numeric type, then recast it to a string, then check if the new value is the same as the original value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/C2tGp))

```
$lines = <<<LINES
Bow
18
Alaska
4.5
France
1.5
10
13
45.1
LINES;

$grouped = array_fill_keys(['int', 'float', 'string'], []);
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $lines) as $element) {
    if ($element === (string) (int) $element) {
        $grouped['int'][] = $element;
    } elseif ($element === (string) (float) $element) {
        $grouped['float'][] = $element;
    } else {
        $grouped['string'][] = $element;
    }
}
var_export($grouped);
```